# How enable loader in bx slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

The loader is not enabled in my bxslider, how to enable it

bx slider version 1.4

**JavaScript code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            mode: 'fade',
            auto: true,
            pause: 5000,
            speed: 2000,
            autoStart:false,
            preloadImages:'all',
 });
});
```

In Html the list element contain inner elements

```
<div class="baner-slider">
    <ul class="bxslider">
      <li>
        <span class="baner baner-1 ">
            <span class="bg-shadow">
                <span class="h1">g</span>
                <span class="h4">We es</span>
                <a href="#">learn more</a>
            </span>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="baner baner-2 ">
            <span class="bg-shadow">
                <span class="h1">Nd</span>
                <span class="h4">edefefe</span>
                <a href="#">learn more</a>
            </span>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="baner baner-3">
            <span class="bg-shadow">
                <span class="h1">ry</span>
                <span class="h4">Ags .</span>
                <a href="#">learn more</a>
            </span>
        </span>
      </li>
     <li>
        <span class="baner baner-4">
            <span class="bg-shadow">
                <span class="h1">A</span>
                <span class="h4">A Academia.</span>
                <a href="#">learn more</a>
            </span>
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="arrow" id="arrw">
        <img src="img/icons/arrw.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="event-wrap hidden-xs hidden-sm">
    <a href="http://intlpag.org/" target="_blank"><h4>Visit us at booth #507 at PAG 2017</h4></a>
</div>
```

Comment: The latest version is 4.2.5 I believe. Did you include jQuery before the bxSlider? I don't see any images in your HTML, bxSlider needs something that has height and width.

Comment: The image given as background property of css

Comment: I see, so what exactly is the result you see on screen and what error is in console? I'm also curious do you see any of the images?

Comment: the issue is fixed when i add image as img tag instead   the background url of   <span class="baner baner-N">

Comment: there was no console error or something,all images are visible , verything works well expect the loader 


the images are given as background url of span element ( span with class baner-1, banner2 , banner-3 ,banner-4)



instead of that span tag i use an img tag inside list element now the issue is fixed

Comment: If you still want to use image-background, try removing the `preloadImages:'all',` and instead of a `<span>` use a div

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved when i added img tag inside li

Thanks to zer00ne for help